# Aweber Email Form Won't Display Inline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Working on a form with Bootstrap CSS, have the form class as "form-inline", but for some reason, the form refuses to actually display inline.

Here's a fiddle, showing the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/5wBzE/

Here's the HTML:

```
<iframe id="AweberFormSubmitFrame" style="display: none" name="AweberFormSubmitFrame" src="about:blank"></iframe>
<form id="before_header" target="AweberFormSubmitFrame" method="post" class="form-inline" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl">
<div style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="2074084490" />
    <input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="listname" value="foreverjobless" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.aweber.com/thankyou.htm?m=default" id="redirect_f916c5c4ae42ade190efaef62fd11c16" />
    <input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="FJ:_Header" />
    <input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="email" />
    <input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="" />
</div>
<div class="af-element">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <input class="text form-control" id="awf_field-60198198" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="500" />
    </div>
    <div class="af-clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element buttonContainer">
    <button name="submit" onClick="return _submit_form_header(this.form);" class="submit btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="501">Subscribe</button>
    <div class="af-clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;">
    <img src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/displays.htm?id=TAzsLAwcLCycDA==" alt="" />
</div>
</form>
<div id="after_header" style="width:99%;border:gray 1px solid;display:none;background-color:#ccc;Padding:5px;height:100px;">Thank you</div>
```

Any tips or pointers in the right direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by taking out the unnecessary aweber divs.